# Installing Ubuntu on an Eee PC 1011PX

Tags: installation, xubuntu, flash, usb-drive

I have recently bought myself an Eee PC 1011PX that came with Windows 7 Starter.  I have since upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate, however, I also wish to install Ubuntu on a separate partition.  My question is whether or not this is possible, and whether or not the boot loader that comes with Ubuntu will interfere with the OS Switch that currently allows switching between Windows 7 and [Express Gate Cloud](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RX8B-I74Bxs)?

A quick Google search has revealed that I can install [EeeXUbuntu](http://www.eeesite.net/2007/12/eeexubuntu-install-xubuntu-easy-way.html) on an SDHC, and therefore avoid installing a boot loader altogether. However, it's release date leaves a lot to be desired....  I could always install [Xandros](http://www.xandros.com/) that is more Eee PC friendly, however, I'd be asking the same questions as above.  What's more, I don't think that Xandros is free.

My second question is whether or not Ubuntu can be installed on a SDHC, and executed in a similar fashion to EeeXUbuntu?

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also wish to install Ubuntu on a separate partition.

Yes, it's possible.

> whether or not the boot loader that comes with Ubuntu will interfere with the OS Switch that currently allows switching between Windows 7 and Express Gate Cloud?

Am I correct in assuming that the switch works once you are booted *into* Windows 7? If so, the Ubuntu bootloader (grub) should not affect it. Of course, you will most probably not be able to switch from within Ubuntu to the Express Gate Cloud (but that's when Privacy Mode comes in handy!).

> My second question is whether or not Ubuntu can be installed on a SDHC, and executed in a similar fashion to EeeXUbuntu?

Yes, it can certainly be installed on the SDHC and executed, provided your eee-pc supports booting from SDHC. Ages ago, my eee-PC 901 certainly did (with Ubuntu!), so I don't see why yours wouldn't. Please note that running Ubuntu from SDHC will be noticeably slower once you start doing things inside Ubuntu.

One option you haven't mentioned is [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). This is a Windows installer for Ubuntu which installs Ubuntu on the Windows partition as a virtual hard disk (one large file, minimum 4GB). It then allows you to select Ubuntu at boot-up *from the Windows bootloader*. This way, nothing critical is changed, and WUBI will certainly be much, much faster than running from SDHC. Besides, it's safer -- what if you accidentally eject the SDHC when you're working?

Comment: Thanks izx!  I'll give WUBI a go!  Sounds a lot safer.  I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: Hi izx, while I was waiting for wubi to download, I looked through the ASUS manual and discovered that Express Gate Cloud is not part of Windows 7.  It is, in fact, an ASUS exclusive OS (based on linux) that provides you with quick access to the internet and key applications without entering the Windows OS.  What does this mean for wubi?  Well, I did another Google search to find out that it is safe to install, and won't overwrite Express Gate, according to the following [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1531886). Will let you know how I go with the install.

Comment: Success! Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using wubi, which is a Windows Ubuntu Installer. The good thing is that I didn't lose ASUS Express Gate!!!  Once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome, Bill! Glad to know everything is working well. I realize now that the Express Gate "Cloud" is the same Express Gate Asus has had for a while -- they actually have some separate flash memory in the laptop upon which the Express Linux installation lives -- it's not on the hard disk. It's extremely difficult to damage it for this reason, and it's also not affected by installing other operating systems. Enjoy Ubuntu!